# Subset data based on character vector

Tags: r

I have character vector containing numeric values. I want to subset data based on the vector.

```
x = '1,2,3,4,5'
n = noquote(gsub(","," ",x))
mtcars[n,]
```

It's not working.

But the following code works.

```
d = data.frame(n = 1:5)
mtcars[d$n,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is a string and not a numeric vector to use it as a row index. We can split the string on ",", convert the numbers into numeric and then subset the dataframe.

```
mtcars[as.numeric(strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]), ]

#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

For comparison purposes, look at below output to understand why your second attempt works.

```
class(d$n)
#[1] "integer"
length(d$n)
#[1] 5

class(x)
#[1] "character"
length(x)
#[1] 1
```